# How can I make a horizontally scrollable component that is placed in my UIViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains two smaller views: `mapView` and `imageView` placed one above the other:

[image]

I want to change it so when the user open this view controller, he will see the map and the dotted element below, something like this one:

[image]

but it should refer only to those two elements on the page - the rest should stay untouched when user swipes back and forth.

I saw some tutorials that places those dots on the very bottom of the screen and then the whole screens are scrollable, but is it achievable only with selected components on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use scroll view with paging enabled as suggested above -

Your class should be a subclass of UIScrollViewDelegate
You will need an IBOutlet of your scroll view. (say scroll)

In your viewDidLoad -

```
//First set frame and content size for scroll view.
scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 120)
scroll.delegate = self
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, 120)

//Then create your imageView and mapView and add them to the scroll view.
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scroll.frame.width, 100))
//Do whatever changes you want in the imgView
scroll.addSubview(imgView)

let viewForMap = UIMapView(frame: CGRectMake(scroll.frame.width, 0, scroll.frame.width, 100))
//Do whatever changes you want in the viewForMap
scroll.addSubview(viewForMap)

var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 20, 100, 40, 20))
pageControl.numberOfPages = n //2 in your case
pageControl.currentPage = 0  //For initial page
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
view.addSubview(pageControl)
```

For showing current page indicator on page control you will need -

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

If you follow the above with whatever changes that suits you, you can develop what you want.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` for scrolling and a `UIPageControl` for showing "The dotted element" as you quoted.

Comment: ok, I placed the `uiscrollview` and put the map inside, but how can I add the 2nd element (`uiimageview`) and connect it with `uiPageControl`?

Comment: You have to implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`, it has some functions that will inform you if scrollViewOffset changed or if it's paged, it's page changed, and on change, set UIPageControl's current page.